# Get file modify date in C#

Tags: c#, file

How do I read the modify date of the file in C#?

I can read the creation date of the file by using the code below:

```
ModifyDate = File.GetCreationTime(FilePath)
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[File.GetLastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx) will do the job

Comment: dang, beat me by seconds

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: I know I'm late to the party and this was (basically) the right answer, but technically, `DateTime lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(strFilePath);`, would be more accurate...  It would've been nicer had I not had to look up how to *actually* do it, from this answer.

Answer (score 13):

I believe you're looking for [GetLastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx)